# Problems with Darksnow with Raspbian stretch

Tags: audio, streaming

I am new to the Raspberry Pi, but have a basic knowledge of command line input.I have installed darkice and darksnow on Raspbian stretch with GUI, I can open darksnow, and set up all of the options and save to a cfg file. When I click "start streaming", the window just closes with no message at all. Any help please.

Comment: if you mean the darksnow log, then that is empty.

Comment: check any log file that has an update time after the time that the window closes .... look for darkice log .... it may send messages to stdout instead of a log file